# Use AJAX to check for a new message

Tags: php, ajax

Quite simply, I need to alert the end user when they have a new private message.
From a combination of research and other opinion, I realise I need to use AJAX for this.

The mysql query would be

```
SELECT id FROM tbl_messages WHERE to_viewed = 1
```

So when someone sends a message, I want an alert to popup on the screen to inform the user without a page reload.

I have absolutely no idea what I am doing, but know what I want.
Really need help with this, AJAX is definitely something I want to improve as it opens up greater possibilities!

Thanks

Comment: You need to tell us what language/framework you're using, PHP, ASP, ASP.NET, Python, Ruby/Rails?

Answer (score 7):

Using jQuery for brevity, if you don't have any JavaScript experience I recommend learning.

```
var check;
function checkForMessages() {
    $.get("/newMessages.php", function(data) {
        if(data == 1) {
            //There are new messages
            clearInterval(check);
            alert("You have new mail!");
        }
    });
}

check = setInterval(checkForMessages, 60000);
```

The above JavaScript will ping the server every 60 seconds. The script "newMessages.php" should return '1' if there are new messages. You have the query already written so I think you can figure it out.

Comment: Hey, I know this is a year old but I'm on the same problem as him. Anyway, I looked through this snippet and it has setInterval and then clearTimeout. Shouldn't it be clearInterval?

Comment: Carrying on from the snippet again. How would you make it continuously check for new messages because right now, it stops once a new message is received and never checks again? =S

Comment: You'd need a bit more logic to handle if there were new messages the last time it checked and not to alert the user

Answer (score 2):

You have two options on the client side:

1. Polling via Ajax:  Every X seconds, send a request to the server to check for messages.
2. Server-push via Comet:  Open a connection to the server and wait for the server to respond with the message.

There are numerous client side libraries available.  For Ajax, you can use JQuery.  For Comet, look into Dojo, but your server/platform must support Comet.  I know it's possible with Java using Jetty, but I'm not sure about other platforms.

Comment: Say if I want to check every 45 seconds.

Comment: You need to take a tutorial on Javascript then. There's a setInterval function which calls a function after x milliseconds. jQuery or Mootools can abstract AJAX calls quite well, I'd recommend jQuery if you're not up on your Javascript.

Comment: Also, to be clear, AJAX is not a language unto its self, it's merely a technology provided by Javascript engines. Asynchronous Javascript and XML as it started. Comet is also Javascript. More or less most dynamic constructs without page reloads are Javascript.

Comment: Is setInterval easy enough to implement?

Comment: I would suggest checking out some tutorials on Javascript, jQuery, and using AJAX. setInterval will not be your hurdle.

Comment: How would it be implemented, I am building a new site and need to know if a script would need to be present on every page. If it's something I can easily add to the site at a later date, I can move on and come back to this.

Comment: I think setInterval i great enough. I used it for the same problem and it worked fine. I'd just suggest you not to set interval less than 10-5 seconds because it hurts the server.